# Why is the horned helmet representative of dragonborn?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

You know the helmet I'm talking about.  It has horns on it.  It's famous.

So this helmet is low quality armor.  I've played through the game a couple of times and I'm not even sure I've seen it.  But so many youtube videos, meme images, and so on feature it as sort of a mascot for skyrim.  Why?  And where did this association come from?  Is it one of those unfortunate instances where something that happens at the beginning of a game (encountering the helmet) becomes representative because a majority don't play through past a couple hours?

Comment: Also, just for clarification purposes, it is a iron helmet, and can be found pretty commonly throughout the game.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only reason this helmet is so much of an icon for Skyrim is because it was the helmet used by the dragonborn in the first in-game trailer (helmet visible starting from around second 50).

Comment: It was also worn in the live-action commercial that appeared on TV.